# Avoid system to open multiple applications in Python

Tags: python

How can I make this code a single instance? Because according to Reddit, it is because that the code for opening applications is inside the while loop. I want to seek a second opinion that's why I'm here.
(Please see the # Open the software applications)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from keras.models import model_from_json
import operator
import cv2
import os
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        # Simulating mirror image
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        
        # Got this from collect-data.py
        # Coordinates of the ROI
        x1 = int(0.5*frame.shape[1])
        y1 = 10
        x2 = frame.shape[1]-10
        y2 = int(0.5*frame.shape[1])
        
        # Drawing the ROI
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1-1, y1-1), (x2+1, y2+1), (0,215,0) ,1)
        
        # Extracting the ROI
        roi = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        
        # Resizing the ROI so it can be fed to the model for prediction
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, (100, 100)) 
        roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, test_image = cv2.threshold(roi, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imshow("test", test_image)
        
      
        result = loaded_model.predict(test_image.reshape(1, 100, 100, 1))
        prediction = {
                      'ONE': result[0][0], 
                      'TWO': result[0][1],
                      'THREE': result[0][2],
                      'FOUR': result[0][3],
                      'FIVE': result[0][4]
                      }
        
        # Sorting based on top prediction
        prediction = sorted(prediction.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        
        # Displaying the predictions
        cv2.putText(frame, prediction[0][0], (10, 120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,140,255), 1)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        
#################################################################################             
        # Open the software applications
        if prediction[0][0] == 'THREE':
            os.startfile("C:\\Program Files  (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")

#################################################################################            
           
        # Press the ESC key to close the frame
        interrupt = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if interrupt & 0xFF == 27: # esc key
            break
            
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is a hand gesture recognition system that opens apps. The system is working but every time it detects the gesture, it opens multiple applications.

Comment: you can add a break statement or an if statement checking that if app is already open than don't open it again

Comment: I ran your code (removed the Keras and prediction models) and I see 2 active windows, one of the video stream with a rectangular box and another is a filtered output of the rectangular area. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @Sagar Does the apps open in your PC? If yes, it will open multiple applications and that is the problem.

Comment: @JoshNav No, it's not opening multiple applications on my PC. Check this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Se1JwiW) to see how it is running on my PC

Comment: @Sagar This is the link for my whole project. It includes the models and dataset. The file you will have to run is menu.py   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fgG0ooKpPZKrDnAOGgaPXJ2WTmW-StHv/view?usp=drivesdk